# Rotated component placement in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Here Altium PCB on the picture. I rotate component on 45 degree and place it on the PCB.

1. What is gray area under the component?
2. Should it be rotated also?
3. Can it be a problem if it s not rotated?
4. How can I rotate it if necessary?

[image]

Comment: Is it on any particular layer? Have you tried turning off likely layers first and isolating it?

Comment: It's fine, don't worry

Comment: @TomL. is right. Don't worry about it. It's fine.

Comment: Though it will give an error. Correct me, but the green color indicates rule violence, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's probably (most likely) a component clearance error. Make sure your footprints all have 3D models then clearance will be checked upon these 3D models and you won't have to worry about part outlines (your grey box). You can see the exact error when you hover over the green part.

Comment: Would it be another way to rotate the component in the PCB_library?

Comment: Tom. L. Make your comment as anser? I will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The gray rectangle under the selected component is just a visual indicator that you currently have this component selected. It's just a simple, automatic "box" Altium places there. You can not select, edit or modify this gray indicator box in any way. (At least i don't know any, and i've been working with this tool since 1998. Maybe you could set some parameters in the vast forest of Altiums configurations to hide it or change the appearance, but it would not make much sense to do that imho.)