# Rotating components in Altium Designer, clearance

Tags: pcb-design, altium, footprint, rotary, clearance

I can't find out how to properly rotate 45 degrees components in Altium Designer. I read two topics about that:

[Rotated component placement in Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176075/rotated-component-placement-in-altium)

[How can I rotate a part in Altium without an collision error?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159886/how-can-i-rotate-a-part-in-altium-without-an-collision-error)

However the solution presented there, creating 3D body shape seems not working. The component below was created with Altium's Wizard and it created 3D shape also.
[image]
[image]
[image]

The grey area is not rotating with the component.

-- EDIT

[image]

Comment: This has always been a wreck of a problem..

Comment: In fairness, I can see that there is an actual component collision in your screenshot... Could you post an image that shouldn't generate an error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated post and added new image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same Problem for some hours now. I finally found out that I had to change the placement mode to "Ignore Obstacles" (press 'R'-key once or twice) while dragging a component. 
http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/((Smart+Component+Placement))_AD

Comment: You are Genius, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a 3D body defined, there is no problem. You can see in the image below, that the selection outline is, indeed, square, but the nearby capacitor does not cause a collision.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's true. Altium is not reporting any problem, but I can't move other components over this grey area. So, having such components as above, U1 and C1, I can't move C1 over U1's grey area.

Comment: @VIPPER What do you mean? What does Altium do if you try to move the component?

Comment: When I click to move the component, I can move the cursor over grey area but the component stays outside. Just like Altium is blocking this area to not move any component over it. I mean, in the image you attached here, the C1 capacitor couldn't be moved to the place it is. It would stay outside grey area.

Comment: @VIPER I have never seen Alitium do this. Can you share your PCB file?

Comment: @Armandas is right, you should be able to move any components over the grey area, it's just the way altium highlights the rotated components. It has nothing to do to constraints.